# Define friend function outside class definition when the class and function have separate template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, friend

The following code compiles fine (just a minimal example, the actual code has more of a reason for this particular layout):

```
template<int A>
class Foo {
    template<int B>
    friend int bar(Foo<A> a, Foo<B> b) {
        return A * B;
    }
};

int main() {
    return bar(Foo<0>(), Foo<1>());
}
```

However, I would like to separate the declaration from the definition and put the function definition outside the class definition. I've tried doing it as you would for a member function:

```
template<int A> template<int B>
int bar(Foo<A> a, Foo<B> b) {
    return A * B;
}
```

But that fails to compile because it doesn't seem to be valid syntax:

```
error: too many template-parameter-lists
```

However, merging the two template parameter lists in this definition (`template<int A, int B>`) gives a linker error:

```
undefined reference to `int bar<1>(Foo<0>, Foo<1>)'
```

That leads me to believe that different template parameter lists cause the compiler/linker to interpret the definition of `bar` as a different function than the declaration.

So my question is: how can I define a friend function outside of the class definition when the class and function have separate template parameters?

Comment: To be clear: the linker error happens even if the single-`template` function definition immediately follows the class template definition (in the same file)?

Comment: @Angew Yes, I put all code in the same file to test my minimal examples

Comment: I think Rakete1111's answer is correct. So... interested in a workaround? https://wandbox.org/permlink/jrHIq5sSSQ8lUPYd

Comment: @bogdan At the moment only one short function has this issue in my code, so I prefer not to add a lot of boilerplate for that. I'm probably leaving the definition inside the class definition or making it a member function. Since the function in question is `operator*` it doesn't matter too much whether a friend or member function is used for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3):

I think that there is no way to do this. Well there is but not generically. You can always explicitly write the overloads for each `A`:

```
template<int B>
int bar(Foo<0> a, Foo<B> b) {
    return 0 + B;
}
```

Basically, the reason is that a different `bar` overload is defined for each instantiation of `Foo`. For example, for `Foo<0>` you'll get a

```
template<int B>
int bar(Foo<0>, Foo<B>);
```

For each instantiation of `Foo`, you will get a new `bar` template. All those `bar`s are independent, because they use a template parameter that exists outside of `bar` itself (from the outer template that is).

You can't use the double `template<>` syntax because that would mean you have two things (class, function, ...) that are a template. This is not the case here, as you only have `bar` as a template. There is nothing else for the first/second `template<>`.

You can't merge them, because as you saw, you'll get a different function. If you look at the instantiated `bar` above for `Foo<0>`, you can see that this is different than:

```
template<int A, int B>
int bar(Foo<A>, Foo<B>);
```

The instantiated version will always be a better match because it doesn't have to deduce anything for the first parameter.

Comment: But then `bar` is a friend of all `Foo<A>` instantiations, not just the one used as first argument.

Comment: @cp.fe.cp Oh so you have certain specializations that `bar` shouldn't have access to? In that case you can just delete specific `bar` overloads.

Comment: How does that work? Won't `bar` still have access to private members of `b` which is not the case in the original code?

Comment: @cp.fe.cp Yes `bar` can access the private members of `b` (and `a` for that matter) but that is also true for the code you posted.

Comment: That's not true for the code I posted, only private members of `a` are accessible (given `A != B`). [Click here for example code.](https://onlinegdb.com/Hky83pHaG)

Comment: @cp.fe.cp Oh no, I'm sorry. I didn't even listen to my own advice, as my answer contradicts what I just said :/ Thank you. So, I don't think there is a  way, sorry.

Comment: Downvoter: Why? Is there anything not accurate that you would like to mention? Did I say something obviously wrong? Please help me